# Pass Chartkick chart type to partial via local var (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, partial-views, chartkick

I've created a chart partial for rendering Chartkick charts in my app. I want to pass 3 locals variables to the partial which provides:

- type of chart (line_chart)
- data
- caption

The data and caption work fine by I can't pass the type of chart. I've tried strings

```
locals: { chart_type: "line_chart", data: @chart, caption: "Some caption" }
```

I've tried instance variables:

```
locals: { chart_type: @type, data: @chart, caption: "Some caption" }
```

And I've tried symbols:

```
locals: { :chart_type => line_chart, data: @chart, caption: "Some caption" }
```

The only thing that works is taking out the chart_type local var and inputing directly into the partial as such:

```
# charts/_chart.html.erb
<div class = "col-12 col-md-10 offset-md-1 chart">
  <%= line_chart data %>
  <h4><%= caption %></h4>
</div>
```

While this is fine for line_charts, I'm unable to pass other types which negate the simplicity of using the partial site-wide.

**ANY IDEAS?**

Comment: Have you tried on the partial `<%= send(chart_type, data) %>` ?

Comment: Those 3 examples are all different? first is a `String` (probably the best solution in combination with @MicaelNussbaumer's comment). Second is an instance variable of unknown type (maybe what you want). Third is a local variable or method (probably not what you want).

Comment: Triggers ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `chart_type'

Comment: @engineersmnky - I know they are different, I'm simply not sure how to pass the string literal to embedded ruby in a partial

Comment: @DawgOnKing the send requires the local `chart_type`

Comment: @engineersmnky - I'm using that as a local but it's not passing the value regardless of what method I try.

Comment: Please post the full render it should look something like `<%= render 'charts/chart', chart_type: "line_chart", data: @chart, caption: "Some caption" %>` and then the partial should be  `<%= send(chart_type, data) %>` in place of  `<%= line_chart data %>`

Comment: @engineersmnky - your above works. The only difference between what you provided and what I was trying was the way I was calling the partial in my view. I was using the following format: `<%= render partial: 'charts/chart', locals: { chart_type: "line_chart", data: @chart, caption: "SOME CAPTION" } %>`